# Printing the entire row where the input matches the element of an array

Tags: java, arrays

How to print the entire row where the input matches the element of an array?
Please have a look on my code where did i go wrong... :(

```
package scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeInformation {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    static String info[][] = {{"09-001", "Ja Gb", "100", "10", },
                        {"09-002", "Justine", "200", "20", ""},
                        {"09-003", "Ja Ja", "150", "15", ""}};

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.print("     - MENU -\n");
        System.out.print("A. Search Record\nB. Payroll Summary\n------------------\nEnter choice: ");
        String choice = null;
        choice = sc.nextLine();


        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            System.out.print("Enter Employee #: ");
            String EmpNum = sc.nextLine();
            SearchRecord(EmpNum);
        }
        else {
                PayrollSummary();
            }
    }

    private static void SearchRecord(String employeeNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String row[] = new String[3];
        int i = 0;
        while(i <= info.length) {
            int j = 0;
            while(j <= info.length) {
                if(employeeNumber.equals(info[i][j])) {
                    for (int a = 0; a <= row.length; a++) {
                        row[a] = info[i][j];
                        System.out.print(row[a]);
                        a++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("Invalid employee number.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    private static void PayrollSummary() {

        System.out.println("Employee #:\tEmployee Name\tRate per Hour\tTotal Hours Worked\tGross Pay");
        int r = 0;
        while ( r <= info.length - 1) {
            int c = 0;
            while ( c <= info.length ) {
                System.out.print(info[r][c] + "\t\t");
                if (c == 3) {
                System.out.print("\n");
                }
                c++;
            }
            r++;
        }



        //for (int a = 0; a <= info.length -1; a++) {
        //      Integer.parseInt(info[a][4]) = Integer.parseInt((info[a][3]) *  (info[a][4]));

        //}
    }
}
```

What should i do when the input matches an element? please give me a hint

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the employee number always as the first element in the 2d array. In that case you do not need a nested loop at all:

```
String[] matchedRow;
for(int i=0; i<info.length; i++)
{
    String[] oneRow = info[i];
    if(oneRow[0].equals(employeeNumber))
    {
        matchedRow = oneRow;
        break
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<matchedRow.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(matchedRow[i]);
}
```

That said, in real life, you would seldom have the employee records in a array like yours. You would create an `Employee` class and have a `List` of `Employee` objects. 
If the `Employee` class is designed correctly with a correct implementations of [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), the match method will be as simple as:

```
employee = employeeList.get(employeeList.indexOf(employee));
System.out.println(employee);
//Do whatever with employee
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved now my problem but i have another problem but i guess i can solve it my own. im wondering in this syntax,     'array[][]' , is it array[columns][rows]?

Comment: It is `[rows][columns]`. Scroll down [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and see multi dimensional arrays. Note, multi dimensional arrays in Java are actually arrays of arrays, so there is no real columns here `arr[0]` in a 2D array is another array. `arr[0][0]` is the first element in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class Employee {

     static String info[][] = {{"09-001", "Ja Gb", "100", "10", },
            {"09-002", "Justine", "200", "20", ""},
            {"09-003", "Ja Ja", "150", "15", ""}};


     private static void search(String employeeNumber) {


        for (String s[] : info ) {
            if(employeeNumber.equals(s[0])) {
                for (String row : s) {
                    System.out.println (row) ; 
                }
                return ;
            }       
        }

        System.out.println ("Nothing found") ; 

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        search ("09-003");
    }//end of main


}
```

Comment: Thanks @MD. Sahib Bin Mahboob :) Would you please explain to me this part <br/>
     'for (String s[] : info ) {
            if(employeeNumber.equals(s[0])) {
                for (String row : s) {
                    System.out.println (row) ; 
                }
                return ;
            }       
        }

        System.out.println ("Nothing found") ;'

Comment: I have used a for loop as foreach loop. Aren't you familiar with this kind of looping ?

Comment: Not really. Im a beginner. sorry for the dumb question

Comment: @user1695813 we all were bargainers one day , so no worry . You can see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) if you want to know something about this style of for loop.